# how do I use a function as a variable in lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a function which checks if every element in the list x has property a, so I wrote:

```
(defun check (a x)
  (if (listp x)
    (eval (cons 'and (mapcar #'a x)))))
```

but it doesn't work. (Basically I want `a` to be the name of a function, say `blablabla`, and in the body of the check-function, by `#'a` I want to mean the function `blablabla`, instead of a function called `a`.) Now the code above doesn't work. I think in Lisp one should be able to plug in functions. How can I fix it?

(It is literally my first day on lisp, so it might be a stupid question ;) 
and BTW I'm using Lispworks 6.0 personal version.)

Comment: It might be useful if you elaborate a bit on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Using EVAl in this case is a mistake.

Comment: Common Lisp btw. already provides this function. It is called EVERY.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I guess eval is like a nuclear weapon that is too powerful for use? forgive my ignorance. :)

Comment: great to know the "every" function! interesting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to use the sharp-quote syntax here.  Its purpose is to use a function name in a variable position, but `a` is a variable already.  Just write `a` instead of `#'a`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `eval` you can use `apply`.
To the problem: You need `funcall` because you provide `a` as argument. (Edit: Not in this case.) By quoting you just refer to the function `a` not the a in this function.

```
(defun check (a xs)
  (if (listp xs)
      (every #'identity (mapcar a
                                xs))))
```

Better, use `loop`:

```
(defun check (a xs)
  (if (listp xs)
      (loop for x in xs
            always (funcall a x))))
```

Best, use `every`:

```
(defun check (a xs)
   (if (listp xs)
     (every a xs)))
```

Comment: `funcall` is unnecessary in this case.  `mapcar` accepts a function designator as its first argument, so assuming that `a` evaluates to a symbol, `(mapcar a ...)` will work just fine.

Comment: Also, you can't `apply` `and`, which is a macro.  There is a function called `every` that is often used instead (though you need to combine it with something like `identity` in this particular case).

Comment: I tried that and I got "Error: AND names a macro -- bad arg for FUNCTION." that's why I turned to eval...

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would write something like your check function. I tried to give it a more descriptive name.

```
(defun are-all-elements-fullfilling-fun-p (fun ls)
  (every #'identity (mapcar fun ls)))
```

**Edit:** Note that a shorter and better definition is

```
(defun are-all-elements-fullfilling-fun-p (fun ls)
      (every fun ls)))
```

Now let's say we want to call it with this function. Note that I tend to use declarations when possible. I quite often screw something up and debugging is easy if the compiler can figure the error out. Also the code will run faster.

```
(defun is-even-p (n)
  (declare (type number n))
  (the boolean (= 0 (mod n 2))))
```

You have to place the #' here:

```
(are-all-elements-fullfilling-fun-p #'is-even-p '(1 2 3 4))
(are-all-elements-fullfilling-fun-p #'is-even-p '(38 2 4))
```

Comment: Adding declarations everywhere makes the code harder to change, and there's no guarantee it will improve the speed - it can also make things slower. It's not a win-win proposition.

Comment: I agree. For the problems I work on it is often helpful, though.

Comment: I really can't see how your `ARE-ALL-ELEMENTS-FULFILLING-FUN-P` function could be in any way different from `EVERY`. Under what circumstances is your definition better than just skipping the `#'IDENTITY` and `MAPCAR` calls?